# Google Visualization : how to show some icon at the top of a column

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I have a simple bar chart in my app, and I need to place some ".", some icon, or anything else at the top of my bar.

Here is the code:

```java
DataTable data = DataTable.create();
data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Year");
data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Sales");
data.addRows(2);
data.setValue(0, 0, "Work");
data.setValue(0, 1, 14);
data.setValue(1, 0, "Sleep");
data.setValue(1, 1, 10);

BarChart barChart = new BarChart(data, options);
vpnl.setHeight("500px");
vpnl.add(barChart);
```

And here is the output, the black circle you can see here is what i want to place at this location, or it can be any number.

Any idea ?

[image: Screenshot of what is produced by the code]

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not currently supported. The only way to implement it is to write some fancy javascript to create it.

I am no pro at working with SVG with javascript, and won't pretend to be. I'll let you know what I found out with Firebug, and share that.

Using [this chart](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#area_chart) I inspected the SVG element that's created. It has 5 different `<g>` (I'm assuming group) elements.

- `g[1]` contains information on the title.
- `g[2]` contains the legend
- `g[3]` contains the chart information (sub-groups with the chart
  area, gridlines, series, axis label values, etc.) -- when a point is
  selected, this shows the circle/double-circle for that point too
- `g[4]` contains axis titles
- `g[5]` contains the tooltips in two separate groups, but only on
  mouseover

Here is the function in the code that gets triggered when you mouseover a point:

```
Y.Ov=function(a,b,c){a=new kv(a);var d=this.Mf.pk(Wj);b=b[zc](sd);d[w](this.Mf[sb](b[0]));for(var e=1;e<b[L];++e)d[w](this.Mf.pk(ti)),d[w](this.Mf[sb](b[e]));Qt(d,c);a.t()[w](d);a.Zz(100);a.Yz(100);this.on[y](a);return a};Y.appendChild=function(a,b){if(b){var c;if(b[Bc]==Sv){if(!b.Th())return;c=b.t()}else c=b;a.t()[w](c)}};Y.replaceChild=function(a,b,c){a.t().replaceChild(b,c);Cu(c)};Y.Fg=function(a){a.Th()&&this.xs(a.t())};Y.xs=function(a){this.Mf.Fg(a)};Y.ds=function(a){this.Mf.removeNode(a);Cu(a)};
```

This probably doesn't help you. I can't find any easy way to create a workaround for this (oh-so-needed) feature. Sorry there's no solution yet!