# Bar chart with values placed on the chart instead of in tooltip

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart

i'm trying to create some charts with google charts api. I need a bar chart with values placed directly on the chart (not on the tooltip which is set by default). I know that it was possible in Image Charts (which are now deprecated). Is there any way to achive a similar result in Google Charts? I will be grateful for any help or advice...

Here are some examples of what i want to achieve:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249247/google-visualization-how-to-show-some-icon-at-the-top-of-a-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. See the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249247/google-visualization-how-to-show-some-icon-at-the-top-of-a-column/15262949#15262949).

Quote follows:

---

This feature is not currently supported. The only way to implement it is to write some fancy javascript to create it.

I am no pro at working with SVG with javascript, and won't pretend to be. I'll let you know what I found out with Firebug, and share that.

Using [this chart](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#area_chart) I inspected the SVG element that's created. It has 5 different `<g>` (I'm assuming group) elements.

- `g[1]` contains information on the title.
- `g[2]` contains the legend
- `g[3]` contains the chart information (sub-groups with the chart
  area, gridlines, series, axis label values, etc.) -- when a point is
  selected, this shows the circle/double-circle for that point too
- `g[4]` contains axis titles
- `g[5]` contains the tooltips in two separate groups, but only on
  mouseover

Here is the function in the code that gets triggered when you mouseover a point:

```
Y.Ov=function(a,b,c){a=new kv(a);var d=this.Mf.pk(Wj);b=b[zc](sd);d[w](this.Mf[sb](b[0]));for(var e=1;e<b[L];++e)d[w](this.Mf.pk(ti)),d[w](this.Mf[sb](b[e]));Qt(d,c);a.t()[w](d);a.Zz(100);a.Yz(100);this.on[y](a);return a};Y.appendChild=function(a,b){if(b){var c;if(b[Bc]==Sv){if(!b.Th())return;c=b.t()}else c=b;a.t()[w](c)}};Y.replaceChild=function(a,b,c){a.t().replaceChild(b,c);Cu(c)};Y.Fg=function(a){a.Th()&&this.xs(a.t())};Y.xs=function(a){this.Mf.Fg(a)};Y.ds=function(a){this.Mf.removeNode(a);Cu(a)};
```

This probably doesn't help you. I can't find any easy way to create a workaround for this (oh-so-needed) feature. Sorry there's no solution yet!

Comment: Thanks for the reply:) I guess i would have to write my own implementation of this type of chart.