# How do I superimpose text on a Google chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts to draw some data into a Stacked Area Chart, which looks something like this:
[image: Stacked Area Chart with lots of data series]

As you can see, there are quite a few data series in this chart. It's really nice that when I hover my mouse over any one of them, it automatically shows me what the values are for that series, for that month. It would be nicer still if I could **simultaneously see the total amount for each month** as well, **as text superimposed on top** of each of the "peaks."

In other words, I *want* it to look more like this:
[image]

Is there some way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bar chart with values placed on the chart instead of in tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278347/bar-chart-with-values-placed-on-the-chart-instead-of-in-tooltip)

Comment: This isn't currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack to get what you want:

```
// assumes your DataTable contains 1 month column and all other columns are the data series in your chart
var columns = [];
for (var i = 0, i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    columns.push(i);
}
columns.push({
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 1, i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
            sum += data.getValue(row, i);
        }
        return sum.toString();
    }
});
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns(columns);
```

Use the view to draw the chart instead of the DataTable, and you should have the labels you are looking for.